# Const variables allocated in some other data region other than rodata region

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I have "const char *x " variable, After compilation it should be alllocated in the rodata region . But when I see the variable x is getting allocated in some data region. Could any one tell If there is any command to  make the const variables to be allocated in the rodata region. During Compilation setting options like that??

Answer (score 2):

`x` is not a constant, but a pointer to `const char`.

You have to make `x` `const`:

```
const char * const x = ...;
```

Note that you have to initialize `x` with the *definition*, as it is a constant variable (pointer) now.

Comment: Its actually something like this "const char buf[DEF_BUF_SIZE]"  declared globally . Sorry for before one.

Comment: @Nina: That is a completely different question then!